# Invalid Product error from Google Play

Tags: android, cordova, google-play

I'm attempting to get https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase working for Cordova/PhoneGap and I'm getting an "Invalid" error when I try to retrieve the product info.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but here is what I have done:

- The plug-in is installed with the proper billing API key in platforms\android\res\values\billing_key.xml
- The store.ready() event does fire without errors, so I know I'm at least connecting.
- I've uploaded a signed APK to Beta and published it.
- I created an in-app purchase and confirmed it is active.
- I confirmed I'm calling the right product ID within the code by hard-coding the ID.
- I get callbacks from `store.when("product").updated(fnProcessProduct)`, but the product.state is always store.INVALID

Is there something I'm missing, either within Google Play, PhoneGap, deploying, or the plug-in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer - once you upload an APK to Google Play as beta and activate your IAP product, you must test using APKs signed with the same key.  I was using Ionic, and Ionic was signing with a debug key.

More info: https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/issues/75